# mysql - how to import database dump with numeric table names

Tags: database, mysql

I'm trying to dump and import a database that has only numeric table names. There isn't much I can do about the naming convention and I know it should not be numeric but that's how it is!

The problem I have is that dumping is ok but when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
Unknown table '0'
```

this occurs at the following line:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `0`;
```

So the question is, is there a way to dump the database and include the database name in front of the table name (workbench does this automatically) or can I change my import so it appends the database name during the import to get this working?

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE `dbname`.`0` ( ... )
```

Or is there any other way of resolving this ?

thanks

Sam

Comment: `drop table if exists 0` (with quotations); works fine for me, my version is  5.6.16, it is the same for you ?

Comment: I'm on 5.1.73, ill try updating to see if that helps

Comment: ktaria: upgrading from the stock mysql you get with Centos 6 to mysql 5.5 worked, please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists `0`
```

works fine for me,
I think it is a problem of mysql version 
 my version is **5.6.16**,